# stein equation proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, operator-theory, normal-distribution

This time I want to prove the stein equation for the 1D gaussian version which is stated below:

```
A random variable X follows the standard normal distribution (i.e x ~ N(0,1))
  if and only E[f'(x) - xf(x) ]= 0     for all smooth function f
      where f'(x) means the derivative of f
```

The proof for the left to the right direction is straightforward. The question is about the converse proof.

**Following is my proof and I am stuck in some weird conclusion. Please check where the error is.**

First, denote the distribution of x by p(x) i.e x~ p

1) let $f'(x) - xf(x) = g(x) - E_q[g(x)]$ for some function g(x) and some arbitrary distribution q

2) f can be obtained with a 1d differential equation by multiplying $e^{(-x^2/2)}$ to the both side when f has a proper zero-boundary condition.

Then $f(x) = e^{x^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^x(g(t) - E_q[g(t)])e^{-t^2/2}dt$

That is, I can get the proper function f when g(x) is given.

3) let $g(x) = 1(x<=x_0)$ where 1 means the indicator

Then, by the condition we have

$0 = E_p[f'(x) - xf(x)] = E_p[ g(x) - E_q[g(x)] ] = E_p[g(x)] - E_q[g(x)] = p(x<=x_0) - q(x<=x_0)$

4) Finally, we get $p(x) = q(x)$ because for any $x_0,  p(x<=x_0) = q(x<=x_0)$ satisfies.

Then the conclusion is that the distribution of p is equivalent to any arbitrary distribution, not standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is unnatural to answer my question but I need some space for what I got.

At the second step, $f(x)$ should be a smooth function. That is, as x goes infinity f should not diverge.

Therefore, 
$\lim_{x->\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x[g(t) - E_q(g)]e^{-t^2/2}dt = 0$

Thus, $E[g(Z)] = E_q(g)$ for Z ~ N(0,1) and for any function g

Then pick up the function g to be step function

It gives that the distribution q should be a standard normal distribution.

i.e if q is not a standard normal distribution then f diverge as x goes infinity

when q is a standard normal then I think I can prove f converges to zero by L'hospital theorem

$\lim f(x) = \lim_{x->\infty} {\int_{-\infty}^x [g(t) - E_q(g)] e^{-t^2/2}dt \over e^{-x^2/2}}   = \lim_{x->\infty} {[g(x)-E_q(g)]e^{-x^2/2} \over -xe^{-x^2/2}} = 0 $ for some bounded function g